# Struggling to understand Raycast node behavior

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am trying to use the Raycast geometry node to apply different textures to surfaces lit by a point light and surfaces in the dark.
But I don't understand the results obtained. The "set material" node applies the red colored material.
First with just the raycast node, without light source position consideration:
[image]
Why is the non exposed side of the sphere getting this weird pattern instead of being the default material all over?

Then with the light source location as origin for the rays:
[image]

And finally when the light source location is obtained via "Capture Attribute" node:
[image]

Why are the two situation with the light source position failing. And why are they not even giving the same results?
My expected result would be to have the bright side of the sphere in the red material and the dark side in white but obviously that's not what is happening here.

Answer (score 2):

In this minimal version:

- *Raycast* casts a ray from each point of the geometry towards the given light-object
- The target of the *Raycast* is the geometry itself. This opens the way to floating-point error: the ray is likely to hit the point it is cast from.
- So a tiny fraction of the point -> light vector is added to the ray source position, for clearance. (The 'Multiplier' in the Epsilon frame is 0.00001)
- The light-object can't be hit, so it's sufficient to test whether or not there is any hit at all.

[image]

The Boolean attribute can be picked up as 0/1 by a shader:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i fear you have a misunderstanding, what the ray_cast node does.

The idea of it is to cast a single ray for each position vector in the specified direction and evaluate if it hits the target geometry. Using the light source as position origin propably only casts one ray.

Maybe dig deeper into the ray_cast node first.